# Why does my receiver's class instance method not receive any data?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, this, instance

I created a basic emitter and receiver. Please can you let me know why when I console log the receivers messages it returns an empty array?

```js
class Emitter {
  constructor(messages = []) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.event = () => {};
  }
  setEvent(fn) {
    this.event = fn;
  }
  trigger() {
    this.messages.forEach(message => this.event(message));
  }
}

class Reciever {
  constructor() {
    this.messages = []
  }
  ping(message) {
    console.log(message)
    this.messages.push(message)
  }
}

const myReciever = new Reciever();
const myEmitter = new Emitter(message = ["A", "B", "C"]);

myEmitter.setEvent(myReciever.ping);
myEmitter.trigger();

console.log(myReciever.messages);
```

Comment: It looks like you are storing everything in the emitter, not the receiver. If you print the emitter, the entries are duplicated

Comment: At the time of `setEvent` the code doesn't care about the `this` context of `myReciever.ping`. ... `ping` gets assigned to an emitters own `event` just as function, immediately getting oblivious where it originally did belong to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment above ...

> *"At the time of `setEvent` the code doesn't care about the `this` context of `myReciever.ping`. ... `ping` gets assigned to an emitters own `event` just as function, immediately getting oblivious where it originally did belong to."*

Besides the already suggested solution of actively `bind`ing `thisArg` to its method, one also can adapt the code in a way that one can or has to pass to `setEvent` a methods's target/context alongside the method/function itself. At `trigger` time the method then will be called within this stored context ...

```js
class Emitter {
  constructor(messages = []) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.handler = () => {};
    this.target = null;
  }
  setEvent(handler, target) {
    // `setEvent` might be better renamed to
    // `setHandler` or `assignHandler`, etc.
    this.handler = handler ?? (() => {});
    this.target = target ?? null;
  }
  trigger() {
    this.messages.forEach(message =>
      this.handler.call(this.target, message)
    );
  }
}

class Reciever {
  constructor() {
    this.messages = []
  }
  ping(message) {
    console.log(message)
    this.messages.push(message)
  }
}

const myReciever = new Reciever();
const myEmitter = new Emitter(message = ["A", "B", "C"]);

myEmitter.setEvent(myReciever.ping, myReciever);
myEmitter.trigger();

console.log(myReciever.messages);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are losing context on the `ping` call:

```
myEmitter.setEvent(myReciever.ping);
```

You need to bind it.

```
myEmitter.setEvent(myReciever.ping.bind(myReciever));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are storing everything in the emitter, not the receiver. If you print the emitter, the entries are duplicated.

This is because when you pass in the function to the `.setEvent(...)` you are using `this` which - in this scenario - is referring to the messages from the emitter; it lost the context of the object it belongs to.

Like @MinusFour indicated, you need to bind the function instead.

See demo below

```js
class Emitter {
  constructor(messages = []) {
    this.messages = messages;
    this.event = () => {};
  }

  setEvent(fn) {
    this.event = fn;
  }

  trigger() {
    this.messages.forEach(message => this.event(message));
  }
}

class Reciever {
  constructor() {
    this.messages = []
  }

  ping(message) {
    console.log(message)
    this.messages.push(message)
  }
}

const myReciever = new Reciever();
const myEmitter = new Emitter(message = ["A", "B", "C"]);

myEmitter.setEvent(myReciever.ping.bind(myReciever));
myEmitter.trigger();

console.log(myReciever.messages);
```